# The shelveset associated with the gated check-in ticket does not exist or does not match the value provided in the request

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, checkin, shelveset

Our gated check-in build with tfspreview.com/visualstudio.com hosted version control using Visual Studio 2010 was working great until a few days ago when we started getting the following error: "The shelveset associated with the gated check-in ticket does not exist or does not match the value provided in the request."

I tried switching over to using xxx.visualstudio.com for source control (vs. xxx.tfspreview.com)  and that didn’t get me past the issue.

I switched the CI build to just build each check-in (without the gated check-in feature) and that works without issue.

I tried switching it back to gated check-in after the build worked without it in hopes something might get reset and I still got the same original issue.

I'm not aware of anything that could have changed with our configuration that could have caused this to stop working and have not been able to find any information on this error online to date.

Any ideas on how to correct this? Are any other tfspreview.com/tfs.visualstudio.com hosted version control users using gated check-in also experiencing this?

Comment: Hi Neil, I have same issue, did you find any solution to resolve this issue ?